# Should I create exceptions for every error in Java?

Tags: java, exception

i'm new to Java and I've been studying exceptions, my question is when should I create a custom exception or not.

For example I'm creating a simple app to deposit and withdraw from a Account, right now I have created 3 exceptions, but my account can't have a negative balance, so I would have to create a new exception to handle it in the constructor and possibly other custom exceptions, is it considered good practice to create very specific custom exceptions for each possible error, or should i try to use the more generic exceptions from java?

it has its getters and setters i just didnt put it here to make it short.

```
public class Account {
    private Integer number;
    private String holder;
    private Double balance;
    private Double withdrawLimit;
    
    public Account() {}
    
    public Account(Integer number, String holder, Double balance, Double withdrawLimit) {
        this.number = number;
        this.holder = holder;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.withdrawLimit = withdrawLimit;
    }
    
    public void deposit(Double amount) throws NegativeAmountException {
        if(amount < 0) {
            throw new NegativeAmountException("Amount must be positive.");
        }
        this.balance += amount;
    }
    
    public void withdraw(Double amount) throws AccountingException {
         if (amount > this.balance) {
                throw new AccountingException("Account doesn't have enough balance. Current balance: " + this.balance + ", Withdrawal amount: " + amount);
            }
            if (this.balance <= 0) {
                throw new NotEnoughBalanceException("Not enough balance. Current balance: " + this.balance);
            }
        this.balance -= amount;
    }
```

AccountingException

```
package model.exceptions;

public class AccountingException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public AccountingException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
    
      public AccountingException(String msg, Throwable cause) {
            super(msg, cause);
      }
}
```

NegativeAmountException

```
package model.exceptions;

public class NegativeAmountException extends AccountingException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public NegativeAmountException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

NotEnoughBalanceException

```
package model.exceptions;

public class NotEnoughBalanceException extends AccountingException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public NotEnoughBalanceException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not just use an `IllegalArgumentException` for all three?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer well that is the point of the questions, if I should use something generic like IllegalArgumentException or if would be better to create custom exceptions.

Comment: For exceptions that can be handled  the same, like here and mostly elsewhere, OldDP is right. A different message should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

The choice to create an exception class for every error depends on your specific needs.

If your program has complex error handling and needs to provide specific information about different errors, it may be beneficial to create an exception class for each type of error.

For example, in a game programming context, you might want to have different exception classes for network errors, input errors, and logic errors.

On the other hand, if your program doesn't need to provide much detail about different errors or doesn't have a lot of error conditions, you may be able to get away with using the standard exception classes that Java provides.

In summary, while creating a separate exception class for every error may offer more flexibility and control in your error handling, it's important to consider whether the effort is worth it given your specific requirements.

Comment: So even tho I could create a custom exception for each error, if i have a simple class its fine to use the exceptions that jave provides, in a more complex class, creating custom exceptions would be more benefitial?

Answer (score 1):

Creating custom exceptions in Java can be beneficial for better code organization and handling specific errors effectively. However, the decision to create custom exceptions depends on the context and the complexity of the application.

In your scenario, handling a negative balance could indeed benefit from a custom exception (NotEnoughBalanceException). This allows you to specifically catch and manage situations where the account balance falls below zero.

Regarding whether to create numerous specific custom exceptions or use more generic Java exceptions, it's generally a good practice to strike a balance. Specific exceptions help in granular error handling and provide clearer insights into the issue, aiding in debugging and maintenance. Yet, excessive custom exceptions might overcomplicate the codebase.

Comment: I can see how creating custom hooks could make the codebase more complicated to work with, but isn't it worth to make the codebase more complicated and making debbuging the code less complicated by creating many custom exceptions?

Comment: Creating custom exceptions in Java offers clearer error identification, aiding debugging. However, excessive custom exceptions can overly complicate the code, making maintenance harder. It's beneficial to strike a balance—use custom exceptions for critical, distinct errors, relying on generic Java exceptions for common cases. This approach maintains clarity while avoiding unnecessary code complexity.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your needs.

1. If you need it for further handling such as in:

- Aspects
- returning a specific HTTP status code
- returning a specific error key in the response body

Then it is a necessity to create specific Exception classes.

2. If you are fine with that the client always gets an `Internal server error` message with no further data, then `IllegalArgumentException` with the appropriate message would be sufficient in all cases.

Comment: So when i'm working with web, it is a common practice to create custom exceptions to handle different HTTP status code instead of using a generic exception from java?